# AWT's GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds() not working on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, awt, screen-resolution

I am using `GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds()` to determine the screen sizes and the relative coordinates of all monitors attached to my PC.

The monitors are configured side by side - so Display1 starts just on the right of Display0.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
for(GraphicsDevice dev:GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()){
    System.out.println(dev.getIDstring());
    System.out.println("  "+dev.getDisplayMode().getHeight()+" "+dev.getDisplayMode().getWidth());
    System.out.println("  "+dev.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getHeight()+" "+dev.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getWidth());
    System.out.println("  "+dev.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getX()+" "+dev.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getY());
}
```

Which prints out

```
1.8.0_77
\Display0
  1080 1920
  1080.0 1920.0
  0.0 0.0
\Display1
  1200 1920
  1500.0 2400.0
  2400.0 0.0
```

The information getBounds returns is not correct:

- The resolution (width, height) does not match the actual resolution of 1920x1200
- The offset of 2400 cannot be true, this has to be 1920

How to get the correct screen Bounds (especially the offset of each monitor to the main screen)?

Comment: Don't you have the width and height reversed in the print statements?

Comment: Compared to the common format width x height - yes. But this doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Hi, did you manager to solve this out? I have the same issue, it seems that on Windows 10, to have te real physical resolution out to getBounds, you have to take into account the device's DPI. On Windows 7 this wasn't the case. Have you tried also on Windows 8?

Comment: Windows 8 has the same issue. I've switched off dpi awareness, this seems to solve the problem. But that is just a workaround.